# Ruby hashes. How to display each key as a table on screen?

Tags: ruby, hash, string-formatting

I do have a hash like this.

```
v_cp={"29000"=>["Quimper"],
"29100"=>["Douarnenez",
"Kerlaz",
"Le Juch",
"Pouldergat",
"Poullan-sur-Mer"],
"29120"=>["Combrit",
"Plomeur",
"Saint Jean Trolimon","Pont-L\'Abbe","Tremeoc"],
"29140"=>["Melgven","Rosporden","Tourch"]
```

I would like to print out each key as a table format on screen like this :
[image]

I use :

```
v_cp.each_key{|k| puts "*"+k+"*";}
```

But of course I get this output:

[image]

which is not what I aim to...

I thought of `sprintf` or printf but I'm really lost here...

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Just take a look at these gems (https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) or (https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1):

If the length of each key is fixed you can just slice keys into subgroups and print them out:

```rb
v_cp.keys.each_slice(5) { |a| puts a.join(' ') }
```

If the length can vary, you should also `ljust` strings:

```rb
str_length = 6
v_cp.keys.each_slice(5) do |a|
  puts a.map { |e| e.ljust(str_length , ' ') }.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#print` instead of `#puts` to put line feeds exactly where you want them. Unlike `#puts`, which automatically adds a new line every time it's called, `#print` prints out only the string that is passed to it, so you have to specifically print a new line character to get a new line.

For example, to get five keys that are the same size on each row, as in your first image:

```
example = {
  29000 => ['Bonjour'],
  29100 => ['Ça va?'],
  29200 => ['Hello'],
  29300 => ['Doing ok?'],
  29400 => ['Some text'],
  29500 => ['Something else'],
  29600 => ['More stuff'],
  29700 => ['This'],
  29800 => ['That'],
  29900 => ['The other']
}

example.keys.each_with_index do |key, index|
  print key.to_s
  print ((index + 1) % 5).zero? ? "\n" : '  '
end

# Result:
=begin
29000  29100  29200  29300  29400
29500  29600  29700  29800  29900
=end
```

(I liked two spaces better than one.)

If the length varies, you can use `#ljust` to pad smaller strings with trailing spaces, as Fizvlad mentions.

Consider preferring `#print` over `#puts` to output anything more complex than a simple string. You often can do with one call to `#print` what can take multiple calls to `#puts`, so overall `#print` is more efficient.

Comment: A million thanks for all who took time trying to get me on the right way . Now it works fine. And sorry again for my "non-knowing" of all the subtilities of the language...Thanks again

Comment: @Ronan No apology necessary for not knowing something! Does using `#print` solve your problem, or did you come up with something else?

Comment: I did solve my problem using key.each_slice wich worked fine. Thanks again .